# Problem regarding Conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $n-$ dimensional random variable. This variable can be written as
$\mathbf{X} = \left[\mathbf{X}_1^T\hspace{5pt}\mathbf{X}_2^T\right]^T$. where, $\mathbf{X}_1$ is $m-$ dimensional and $\mathbf{X}_2$ is $n-m$ dimensional. We can find the probability density function (pdf) of $\mathbf{X}$ as,

$p\left(\mathbf{X}\right) = p\left(\mathbf{X}_1,\hspace{3pt}\mathbf{X}_2\right)$
$=p\left(\mathbf{X}_1|\mathbf{X}_2\right)p\left(\mathbf{X}_2\right)$.

However, for the problem I am trying to solve, it's not possible (let's assume it) to find $p\left(\mathbf{X}_1|\mathbf{X}_2\right)$. But I can find $p\left(\mathbf{X}_1|\mathbf{X}_2=x_2\right)$. I also know $p\left(\mathbf{X}_2\right)$. How do I find $p\left(\mathbf{X}\right)$ from $p\left(\mathbf{X}_1|\mathbf{X}_2=x_2\right)$ and $p\left(\mathbf{X}_2\right)$?

Comment: What is the difference between $p(X_1|X_2)$ and $p(X1|X_2=x_2)$ ? You know the conditional $p$ only for some $x_2$? Then it is not enough.

Comment: $x_2$ is an instance of random variable $\mathbf{X}_2$. What I think is that to find $p\left(\mathbf{X}\right)$, I need to know all the possible instances of $\mathbf{X}_2$ and then apply Total Probability Theorem. But for my problem, such approach will be computationally infeasible. That's why I wanted to know if there is another method.

Comment: Arbitrary instance? Then I don't get it. When we define probability distribution - it is function of $X_1,X_2$, which are just instances. So $p(X_1|X_2)$ is distribution of $x$ in $X_1$ given $X_2$. You don't have to assume $X_1,X_2$ are random into $p$.

Comment: Assume that $n=6$, $m=2$. So, $\mathbf{X}_2$ is $4$ dimensional. Assume that one of the instances of $\mathbf{X}_2$ is its mean which is, let's say, $\mu=\left\{4,1.6,10,1000\right\}$.So, I know $p\left(\mathbf{X}_1|\mathbf{X}_2=\mu\right)$. I also know $p\left(\mathbf{X}_2\right)$. So, how to find $p\left(\mathbf{X}\right)$ from these two information.

Comment: Coming back to my first comment. If you know $p(x|x_2)$ only for a particular $x_2$  then it means that you don't know $p(x|x_2)$ as a function of $(x,x_2)$ so IMHO in general unless you know something else you cannot recover $p(X_1,X_2)$.